# Merge two Documents in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, velocity

I have two Documents(.csv), i want to merge it. Is it possible?

Here a example

Document1:

```
<doc>
 <arr name="id">
  <long>200000000</long>
 </arr>
 <arr name="Name">
  <str>Sample</str>
 </arr>
 <arr name="first_name">
  <str>Sally</str>
 </arr>
</doc>
```

Document2:

```
<doc>
 <arr name="id">
  <long>200000000</long>
 </arr>
 <arr name="Street">
  <str>Any Street</str>
 </arr>
 <arr name="State">
  <str>Any State</str>
 </arr>
</doc>
```

It should look like this:

```
<doc>
 <arr name="id">
  <long>200000000</long>
 </arr>
 <arr name="Name">
  <str>Sample</str>
 </arr>
 <arr name="first_name">
  <str>Sally</str>
 </arr>
 <arr name="Street">
  <str>Any Street</str>
 </arr>
 <arr name="State">
  <str>Any State</str>
 </arr>
</doc>
```

How can I do this in Solr? Should I create a second core and merge it somehow?
Or what can I do?

Comment: Add what you have tried so far to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you just do these:

1. index first doc Document1
2. using [partial updates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents) you update that doc, with the additional data:

   ```
   {"id":"200000000",
   "Street":{"add":["Any Street"]},
   "State":{"add":["Any State"]}
   }
   ```

There is just a requirement: all your fields must be stored (stored="true") or docValues(docValues="true")

Answer (score 0):

Merging cores won't help here. As mentioned in detail at [Apache Solr Reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Merging+Indexes), to merge indexes, they must meet some requirements:

*The two indexes must be compatible: their schemas should include the same fields and they should analyze fields the same way.*

Now it depends on your use case.

1. In case you have both updates csv files available at same time you can write a [DataImportHandler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Multiple_DataSources)(for multiple sources) to merge data from both csv files and index on Solr
2. You can define fields for both documents in schema. And can index the first csv file. And partial update the index with second csv file

Answer (score 0):

You should merge those csv files yourself if possible. It is a common problem, you could - for example - use a [Unix join utility](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/01/join-command.html).

If you absolutely have to do it on the Solr side AND you cannot convert one of the files into atomic update, you can keep an eye out on [SOLR-9530](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9530), but it is not yet released.